# Supporting multiple incompatible versions of C++ library

Tags: c++, re2

I wrote [a Ruby C++ extension](https://github.com/mudge/re2) to wrap [Google's re2 regular expression library](http://code.google.com/p/re2/) but a [recent update to the library](http://code.google.com/p/re2/source/detail?spec=svn0c439a6bd7955a70088003071e5119ea73a7d02e&r=d9f8806c004d00cbfed45081afd591f78ab22818) changed the interface of the `Match()` function from:

```
bool Match(const StringPiece& text,
           int startpos,
           Anchor anchor,
           StringPiece *match,
           int nmatch) const;
```

To:

```
bool Match(const StringPiece& text,
           int startpos,
           int endpos,
           Anchor anchor,
           StringPiece *match,
           int nmatch) const;
```

(Note the new `int endpos` argument.)

My question is: is it possible for me to support both versions of this library in one extension despite the fact that re2 does not seem to specify any kind of `VERSION` constant that I can introspect?

Ideally, I want to be able to try the newer version (with 6 arguments) and, failing that, fall back to the older version (as I am able to backfill the `endpos` argument easily).

At the moment my code is like this:

```
matched = p->pattern->Match(text_as_string_piece, 0, (int)RSTRING_LEN(text), RE2::UNANCHORED, 0, 0);
```

But if you have the older version of re2, it needs to be:

```
matched = p->pattern->Match(text_as_string_piece, 0, RE2::UNANCHORED, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional answer is to generate a `config.h` or whatever at installation time.

That is, at installation you will detect which version of `re2` is installed, and then define a symbol in `config.h` depending on this:

```
// config.h
#ifndef CONFIG_H_INCLUDED
#define CONFIG_H_INCLUDED

#define RE2_MATCH_6_ARGS 1

#endif // CONFIG_H_INCLUDED
```

And then, you can use this:

```
#if defined(RE2_MATCH_6_ARGS) && RE2_MATCH_6_ARGS == 1
  matched = p->pattern->Match(text_as_string_piece, 0, (int)RSTRING_LEN(text), RE2::UNANCHORED, 0, 0);
#else
  matched = p->pattern->Match(text_as_string_piece, 0, RE2::UNANCHORED, 0, 0);
#endif
```

This is a stable solution, and should work well.

---

Another possibility is to hack the system...

Provide a definition of both `Match` functions in a wrapper library:

- `Match5` throws an error (please link to re2)
- `Match6` forwards to `Match5`.

The thing is (in the Unix world...), if a symbol has already been loaded, it will not be overwritten by a new definition. So as long as `re2` is loaded first you end up in one of those two scenarios:

- *old* `re2`: your (wrapper) library provides a definition of `Match6` which forwards to the `re2` provided definition of `Match5`
- *new* `re2`: the call directly goes to the definition of `Match6` that `re2` provided

*Much* more brittle. Requires a *wrapper library* around `re2`. Unlikely to work with static linking (never tried though...). But does not require a `./configure` step.

Comment: Both your and @Gui13's answers lead to me to the solution which was to set a `HAVE_ENDPOS_ARGUMENT` flag *before* compilation by compiling a test program that would fail on one version but pass on the other. Sadly, I can pick only one answer and @Matthieu's had an alternative approach which I appreciated during investigation. See the (Ruby-specific) solution at https://github.com/mudge/re2/commit/d3e96038cf46c80de421bdef786097043f0faa3a

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you can't. This would require you to link with both the old and the new versions of RE2, which would make namespaces collide.

Unless there exists a version of this method that ressembles the old version, you're stuck with the new version.

If you want to be able to *compile* your extension for both versions, then you have to modify your compiling steps to define some flag that *you* control.

```
#ifdef RE2_ODLFORMAT
matched = p->pattern->Match(text_as_string_piece, 0, RE2::UNANCHORED, 0, 0);
#else
matched = p->pattern->Match(text_as_string_piece, 0, (int)RSTRING_LEN(text), RE2::UNANCHORED, 0, 0);
#endif
```

Then to compile your code, you'd do something along those lines:

```
make RE2_OLDFORMAT=1 all # compile for old version
make all # default target is for new version
```

Comment: After discussing this with some colleagues, could the setting of this flag be done during a `./configure` stage (viz. check to see if `Match()` takes 5 arguments or 6 and set a flag appropriately)?

Comment: Of course, probably a `--legacy-re2` option of some sort. Activating this flag would add `-DRE2_OLDFORMAT=1` to the CFLAGS of the Makefile.